# Google drive V3 java api syntax for searching files

Tags: java, google-drive-api, drive

My Question is - How to pass the search parameters to the method. There is no any documentation or sample I found for search.Any sample example will work for me.

Source Code

```
      String npTok = null;
      String queryParam ="modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00' and (mimeType 
      contains 'image/' )";
      com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry =    drive.files().list().setFields("files(id, name)").setQ(queryParam);

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList gLst = qry.execute();
        for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File gFl : gLst.getItems())
        { 
            String id = gFl.getId();
            System.out.println("ID==>"+id);
        }
```

Error

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fields",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid field selection name",
    "reason" : "invalidParameter"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid field selection name"
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is objecting to the `fields` parameter, not the `q`. Your syntax is correct for v3, so I suspect your client library is still using v2. Try replacing `files(id,name)` with `items(id,title)`. If that works, you're using an old version of the library.

Comment: I know , I should ask new question, it is kinda related, how to find the folders.  I am usng the following code       String queryParam ="mimeType ='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
    
    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry =    drive.files().list().setQ(queryParam).setCorpus("domain").setSpaces("drive");
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList gLst = qry.execute();               ==> This return zero results , although there are so many folders.

Answer (score 0):

refer bellow link, you can get sample code and more information about  Google drive V3 java api searching.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java

Comment: I tried the exact  phrase{String queryParam ="name = 'hello'";} from above links and it still throws the same error.